# cannot import name 'LSHForest' from 'sklearn.neighbors'

Tags: scikit-learn

```
from sklearn.neighbors import NearestNeighbors, LSHForest
ImportError: cannot import name 'LSHForest' from 'sklearn.neighbors'
```

I came to know that LSHForest is depreciated. So how can use it. do we have any other alternative.

I'm using Sklearn version 1.0.1

Answer (score 0):

The `LSHForest` model has indeed been deprecated and remove from `scikit-learn`. Looking at historical versions it seems that the model has been removed in version 0.21, but was still available in versions before that (even though it was already deprecated). Downgrading your `scikit-learn` version to 0.20 or before should allow you to still use the model.